# how to get video properties values(hue,brightness..)in vc++ directshow

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

`hai..

i have to get video procamp values in vc++.so i wrote like this using IAMVIDEOPROCAMP interface..

```
IAMVideoProcAmp *pc;
    long Property=0;
    long *pMin=0;
    long *pMax=0;
    long *pSteppingDelta=0;
    long *pDefault=0;
    long *pCapsFlags=0;

    hr=Capture_Graph->QueryInterface(IID_IAMVideoProcAmp,(void**)&pc);
    hr=pc->GetRange(VideoProcAmp_Brightness,pMin,pMax,pSteppingDelta,pDefault,pCapsFlags);
```

But i got error in queryinterface line.(E_NOINTERFACE)..

i wrote this code before render preview..

kindly help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This interface will be exposed by one of the filters, not by the graph itself. Use ICaptureGraphBuilder::FindInterface to locate the filter that supports it.